# Init method in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

In

```
src/app/code/myModul/Model/Webforms.php
```

I have a :

```
$this->_init('webforms/webforms');
```

What is it do?

Answer (score 1):

The `_init()` method will define the resource model which will actually fetch the information from the database.

Comment: ok, and where is query in DB?